# Discord.RichEmbed is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I replace **Discord.RichEmbed()** to **MessageEmbed** it is always an error...

When I write MessageEmbed, VSC sends me : *MessageEmbed is not defined*.

When I write Discord.RichEmbed(), VSC sends me : *Discord.RichEmbed() is not a constructor*.

```js
message.guild.channels.create(channelName, { parent: SupportCategory.id, topic: `Ticket Owner :${message.author.id}` }).then(c => {
        const sr = message.guild.roles.cache.get(supportrole)
        const everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "@everyone")
        c.updateOverwrite(sr, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
        });
        c.updateOverwrite(everyone, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
        });
        c.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
        });
        let CreateTicketEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .setTitle('Nouveau ticket !')
            .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}> ton ticket est <#${c.id}> ! Merci de patienter le temps que le staf te prenne en charge.`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter("par ❝ Ɔ  ．#7124")
            message.channel.send(CreatedTicketEmbed)
            let GreetEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#303136')
            .addField(`New Support Ticket`, `<@${message.author.id}> ton ticket est <#${c.id}> ! Merci de patienter le temps que le staf te prenne en charge.`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter("par ❝ Ɔ  ．#7124")
            c.send(GreetEmbed)
    }).catch(console.error);
}),
```

Comment: It should be `Discord.MessageEmbed()`.

Comment: I will test, thx ! :)

Comment: @Jakye VSC say (urgh) "CreateTicketEmbed is not defined" ;-;

Comment: You defined it as `CreateTicketEmbed`, but used it as `CreatedTicketEmbed`.

Comment: @Jakye i don't understand. How ?

Comment: I think what Jakye is trying to say is you need to change `message.channel.send(CreatedTicketEmbed)` to `message.channel.send(CreateTicketEmbed)`.

Comment: @DaemonBeast but this is the same for me ? x)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by *but this is the same for me?*

Comment: @DaemonBeast *message.channel.send(CreatedTicketEmbed) to message.channel.send(CreatedTicketEmbed)*

Comment: Remove the **d** from **Created**, so that it becomes **Create**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the not-so-new discord.js version 12, RichEmbed has been merged with MessageEmbed. You should use the MessageEmbed constructor instead.